# Charge weight and weight Info in chain-extension

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts, chain-extension

I am writing a chain-extension that is a 1 to 1 map of a pallet. Based on [this](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/index.html#benchmarking):

> [...] charging the appropriate amount of weight. In order to do so benchmarks must be written and the charge_weight function must be called before carrying out any action that causes the consumption of the chargeable weight.

I wonder if you should charge weight before any call to the pallet:

```
let base_weight = <T as pallet_dapps_staking::Config>::WeightInfo::bond_and_stake();
env.charge_weight(base_weight)?;
                
let call_result = pallet_dapps_staking::Pallet::<T>::bond_and_stake(
    RawOrigin::Signed(caller).into(),
    contract,
    value,
);
```

Or if the weight will be charged in the pallet call anyway (and the above code might charge the weight two times).

**Also** as chain-extension exposes a `call` function that can dispatch different pallet calls, how to ensure proper weight is handled to not excess max block weight ? basically the equivalent of `#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::extrinsic())]` for pallets.

Code [here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/blob/b2f888fafecb7257e68c5e9f0e9e661d1f8007c9/chain-extensions/dapps-staking/src/lib.rs#L110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if you should charge weight before any call to the pallet:

You need to charge manually as demonstrated in your example. It is only automatically charged when the `Call` is included in an extrinsic and send to the chain.

> Also as chain-extension exposes a call function that can dispatch
> different pallet calls, how to ensure proper weight is handled to not
> excess max block weight ? basically the equivalent of
> #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::extrinsic())] for pallets.

You can have a look at the (unstable) [`call_runtime`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1a1600b827020cae62c9b856cb9ba4b823ab080a/frame/contracts/src/wasm/runtime.rs#L2397-L2450) API in `pallet-contracts` which does exactly this:

```rust
fn call_runtime(
    ctx: _,
    memory: _,
    call_ptr: u32,
    call_len: u32,
) -> Result<ReturnCode, TrapReason> {
    use frame_support::dispatch::{extract_actual_weight, GetDispatchInfo};
    ctx.charge_gas(RuntimeCosts::CopyFromContract(call_len))?;
    let call: <E::T as Config>::RuntimeCall =
        ctx.read_sandbox_memory_as_unbounded(memory, call_ptr, call_len)?;
    let dispatch_info = call.get_dispatch_info();
    let charged = ctx.charge_gas(RuntimeCosts::CallRuntime(dispatch_info.weight))?;
    let result = ctx.ext.call_runtime(call);
    let actual_weight = extract_actual_weight(&result, &dispatch_info);
    ctx.adjust_gas(charged, RuntimeCosts::CallRuntime(actual_weight));
    match result {
        Ok(_) => Ok(ReturnCode::Success),
        Err(_) => Ok(ReturnCode::CallRuntimeReturnedError),
    }
}
```